# Dual space of $R^n$ with $\max$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

So I think it's supposed to be the $(R^n,||.||_1)$, but I can't get one of the inequalities: 
So if $\lambda_k = f(e_k)$, for $f$ in the dual, $x = (x_1,...,x_n) \in R^n$ and $\{e_k\}$ basis, then:
$$|f(x)|  \leq \sum|x_k||\lambda_k| \leq \max|x_k|\sum|\lambda_k|$$
Thus $\||f||\leq \sum |\lambda_k|$
But I don't see how to get the reverse inequlity...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a specific vector $x$ with $x_i=-1$ if $\lambda_i<0$ else $x_i=+1$.
Then $\|x\|_\max=1$ and
$$f(x) =\sum_ix_if(e_i) =\sum_i|\lambda_i|$$